# 条件を満たしていてもユーザーカードに影が付与されない？

Tags: バグ, サポート, ヘルプ

### 不具合事象

ヘルプ センターによれば、以下の条件を満たした場合、ユーザーカードのアイコンに影が付与されます。しかし、現在すべてのブラウザでこれは行われません。

- 信用度 750 点以上
- プロフィールの「自己紹介」に少なくとも 28 文字のテキストが入力されている

> ### 確立したユーザー<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)</sup>
>
> - 権限の種類: マイルストーン権限
> - 授与資格:信用度 750 点
>
> #### 拡張ユーザーカードはどのように表示しますか?
>
> 拡張ユーザーカードは、プロフィールの「自分について」のセクションに少なくとも 28 文字あるときのみ利用できます。プロフィールが十分長くて拡張ユーザーカードを表示できる場合、アバターにドロップ シャドウ エフェクトが表示されます。

---

### 動作環境

- Windows 7, 10
- Google Chrome 最新版
- Mozilla Firefox 最新版

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSE での投稿によれば "status-bydesign" タグが付いており意図的な変更のようですが、
「信用度に関係なくすべてのユーザーに対してプレビューカードを追加する予定」
のような発言がされています。(それからしばらく時間が経つけど予定は未定状態？)

[Drop shadows on avatars eligible for expanded usercard has disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336681)

なお、元に戻す提案も出ていますがこちらはマイナス票と "却下タグ" が付いています。

[Reinstate the drop shadow on user cards in cases where the user card shows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341689)

---

**追記:**
MSEでのアナウンスによれば、この機能が全ユーザー向けに有効となったようです。
表示される条件も "「自己紹介」に**最低6文字以上**" に変更された様子。

[Can we make the “expanded user card” privilege universal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342575/403540)

> I am happy to announce that hover cards are now working for all users. We have removed the rep requirement for this (previously 1000 rep), so it will show for any user. Based on your feedback, we have also moved down the content requirement for showing the hover card from 28 characters to 6 characters. This is now live on all sites on the network, and relevant wiki pages have been updated.

SOjaでの [関連するヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) が更新されました。